# python sort with multiple condition

Tags: python, sorting

[3, 30, 34, 5, 9]

I want to sort this [9,5,34,3,30] 
I tried with

```
numbers.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0]) ,reverse=True)
```

I'm search for the multiple condition sort but stucked

```
def solution(numbers):
    ifprint = True
    result = ""

    numbers_origin = list(map(lambda x: str(x), numbers))
    numbers = list(map(lambda x: str(x) * len(str(max(numbers)))  if len(str(x)) < len(str(max(numbers))) else str(x), numbers))
    numbers = sorted(enumerate(numbers), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
    for  i in numbers:result += numbers_origin[i[0]]
    if len(set(result))==1 and result[0]=="0": result = result[0]


    return str(result)
```

I want to make it faster

Comment: what are your conditions exactly?

Comment: `numbers.sort(key=str,reverse=True)` It looks like you want "natural" sort (although i think you want 3 and 30 swapped from what you listed as your expected output

Comment: @JoranBeasley that will give 30, 3

Comment: I think OP just messed up expected order ... (but im not sure ... hence a comment, with that exact comment)...

Comment: omg ... yes you can make that faster ... you have like a billion loops there good lord man :exploding-head:

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
mxl = 3
def this_is_da_key (x):
    ret = [0 for i in range(mxl)]
    for i,v in enumerate(str(x)): ret[i] = int(v)
    print(ret)
    return ret[0], ret[1], ret[2], -len(str(x))
numbers.sort(key = this_is_da_key, reverse = True)
print(numbers)
```

```
[9, 5, 34, 3, 30]
```

Alternate solution for number up to 10^16

```
numbers = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
mxl = 15
def this_is_da_key (x):
    ret = [0 for i in range(mxl)]
    for i,v in enumerate(str(x)): ret[i] = int(v)
    ret = int(''.join(str(i) for i in ret))
    return ret, -len(str(x))
numbers.sort(key = this_is_da_key, reverse = True)
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Im quite curious if this is actually the expected order, or if op messed up his expected output ... good solution i guess +1 ... as long as no numbers are greater than 1k (but pretty easy to solve if you need more)

Comment: This is my brain overfitting on data given in the question :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have added an alternate solution that works for 10^16, but I am curious what OP wanted

Comment: heres an alt version `sorted([3, 30, 34, 5, 9],key=lambda x:("{0:0<15d}".format(x),-x))`